# SVN - How to keep core source code confidential and give freelancers access to modules only

Tags: svn, copy-protection, modular, source-code-protection

I'm developing a modular propietary PHP application. As a project leader and owner, I want to keep the core engine confidential. The freelancers will work on modules (say 1 freelancer for 1 module where they can't see other's module).

I created repos for core (1 repo) and modules (1 repo for 1 module). AFAIK the repo should be placed outside htdocs. Now I think about this scenario: Using SVN, I'll give access to repo A for freelancer A, repo B for freelancer B, etc. When A checkout, he'll only have module A on his computer to edit. To test his module, he'll commit. But as it goes to svn dir instead of htdocs, he won't be able to test it instantly. He'll then need to export the commited code to htdocs. Well, I want to skip this export step.

(1) Is there a way he can commit his code to htdocs directly to test it to make it more practical?

(2) Is there any better scenario to achieve this (i.e. freelancer only allowed to read/write the module he worked on, and have no access - even read - to other module and core system)?

Comment: Basically, you can create an "after commit" script that will move files to htdocs folder. Problem with this scenario is that, unless you're working on a test server, it is not good for production. Still, it is the simplest way to achieve what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

There are three places you're talking about:

- The Subversion repositories themselves. This is where all the source code will live. The repository will be accessible via a Subversion client which will talk to the server. The server can use the *SVN* protocol or *HTTP/HTTPS*. If you want to use *HTTP/HTTPS*, you'll need to setup an Apache server. If you want to run *SVN*, you will need to have the `svnserve` process running.
- The local working directory on the developer's system. This is where files are checked out to, and where the developer can make changes. It is not necessarily on same machine with the repository.
- The PHP Webserver. This is where the PHP files need to be in order to work and possibly to be tested.

Let's take this one at a time: With either *SVN* or *HTTP/HTTPS*, it is possible to limit who can see, checkout, and commit the code into the repository. In Subversion, you can specify this to a directory level. Thus, one developer can check in code to `http://myserver/svnrepos/module1` while another can check in and out code from `http://myserver/svnrepos/module2`, and neither can see your code at `http://myserver/svnrepos/core`,

The tricky part is getting this information onto the server for testing. The question is how to allow developers to do commits without necessarily putting the code onto the server. There are a couple of ways to do this.

One is to create a *server* branch. If the developer wants the code on the PHP server, they would merge the code onto the *server* branch. Then, you need a mechanism to move the code from the repository to the PHP server.

I would not use a post-commit hook for this purpose. You don't want the developer to wait around for the hook to copy their code to the server. Besides, you probably want to bring the server up and down.

Instead, use a crontab which will watch the Subversion repository (especially the *server* branches), and then when it detects a change, take the server down, update the files in the server, and then bring the server back up. My method is to use two different directories. Have directory1 on the server. Use `svn export` to export the files to directory2. Thus the server is still up. Then, take the server down, and move `directory2` to `directory1`, and bring the server back up. This keeps downtime to a minimum and the server in a more or less stable state.

However, you should look at [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to help you with your project. Jenkins will allow you and your developers to see their changes (you can limit who sees what), do basic testing. For example, you can run [PHPMD](http://phpmd.org/) (see how messy the code is) and [CPD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html) (copy paste detector) after a commit, and Jenkins will show the results. You can then put a *deploy* button on Jenkins, and the developer can deploy their build to the server.

Jenkins is simple to setup and use. There are tons of [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) for various defect tracking systems, Subversion, and various testing modules. I don't know how much is available for PHP, though, but you can take a look.